# Blazor cascading parameters in .net8

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

In previous version of Blazor in .NET 7, when I changed a cascading parameter (from date picker for example), function OnParameterSet was fired. In .NET 8 version, this function doesn't get triggered (after update to new with the same logic).

Is there any chance to get the same action in new blazor version?

Program.cs

```
using CsPropTester;
using CsPropTester.Components;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddCascadingValue("CascadingProps", sp => new CascadingProps { RowId = 0, SysDate = DateTime.Today });

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAntiforgery();

app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();

app.Run();
```

NavHeader.razor

```
@rendermode InteractiveServer
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<div class="offcanvas offcanvas-start" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasCsProp" aria-labelledby="Search">
    <div class="offcanvas-header">
        <h3 id="offcanvasTopLabel">Rows</h3>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close text-reset" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="offcanvas-body">
    @foreach (Row rw in Store.Rows)
    {
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center text-small @(rw.Id.Equals(CscdProps.RowId) ? " active" : "" )" style="padding: 6px;" value="@rw.Id" @onclick="() => SelectItem(rw.Id)">
            @rw.Name
            <small class="text-muted">@rw.Id</small>
        </a>
    }
    </div>
</div>

<nav style="border-bottom: 1px black solid;" class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light navbar-bg border-bottom-1">

    <div class="navbar-nav ms-2">
        <div class="col-auto d-none d-xl-block">
            <label for="iDATE" class="col-form-label">Date: </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto d-block">
            <InputDate id="Klient" class="form-control" ValueExpression="@(() => dateSelect)"
            Value="@dateSelect" ValueChanged="@((DateTime value) => OnDateChange(value))" />
        </div>
    </div>

    @if (CscdProps.RowId != null & Store.Rows != null)
    {
        <div class="navbar-nav ms-2">
            @if (Store.Rows.Count(x => x.Id == CscdProps.RowId) > 0 && CscdProps.RowId > 0)
            {
                <button type="button" class="me-2 d-inline btn btn-outline-secondary" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasCsProp" aria-controls="offcanvasCsProp"><span class="d-none d-sm-none d-md-inline-block d-lg-inline-block d-xl-inline-block d-xxl-inline-block"><strong>@(Store.Rows.First(x => x.Id == CscdProps.RowId).Name)</strong> (</span>ID: @CscdProps.RowId<span class="d-none d-sm-none d-md-inline-block d-lg-inline-block d-xl-inline-block d-xxl-inline-block">)</span></button>
            }
            else
            {
                <button type="button" class="me-2 d-inline btn btn-outline-secondary" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasCsProp" aria-controls="offcanvasCsProp"> Select row </button>
            }
        </div>        
    }
</nav>

@code
{
    [CascadingParameter(Name = "CascadingProps")]
    public CascadingProps CscdProps { get; set; }

    private DateTime dateSelect;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            dateSelect = CscdProps.SysDate;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }

    private async Task SelectItem(int id)
    {
        CscdProps.RowId = id;
    }

    private void OnDateChange(DateTime dt)
    {
        dateSelect = dt;
        CscdProps.SysDate = dt;
    }
}
```

Counter.razor

```
@page "/counter"
@rendermode InteractiveServer

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

<br />
@CscdProps.RowId
<br/>
@CscdProps.SysDate


@code {

    [CascadingParameter(Name = "CascadingProps")]
    public CascadingProps CscdProps { get; set; }

    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }

    protected override Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        return base.OnParametersSetAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the code!

Comment: Offcourse! I've added sample code